# button in jquery and jscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am trying to understand the difference between JQuery and JavaScript.
And apologies if this is a silly question.

This is my attempt at JQuery. On pressing the button the text in `<p>` should change as requested. I cannot get this to work. 
http://jsfiddle.net/QaHda/7/

this is my JavaScript attempt. I cannot get this to work either 
http://jsfiddle.net/aLhb8/1/

Can someone please help me with

1. my jQuery above to get it working.
2. my jscript above to get it working.
3. I was trying to get to a point where I could write my JQuery in such a way that it could be written in javascript. Can anyone help me do this?

Thanks

EDIT

Thanks for all the answers/corrections: what I was looking for part 3 was this [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/aLhb8/7/) which basically does part 1 using javaScript,I think. In future I should be careful,using left hand pane,  to include Jquery library and to make sure jsript is wrapped in head/body

Comment: It helps if you actually include jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QaHda/8/. And your second example needs to have the code in the head of the document, not the load event: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aLhb8/2/

Comment: Terminology note: jQuery **is** JavaScript. They're not different languages; jQuery is just a JavaScript library. When you're writing code that uses jQuery, you're writing JavaScript code.

Comment: Tks j08691!! I get that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery**

You need to include jQuery library to your page by selecting a jQuery version in the first dropdown in the left panel

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zrpvy/1/)

**JS Sample**

The problem is since your function is defined within the onload callback, it was not available in the global scope causing an error saying

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

The solution is to add the script to the body elements, instead of inside the onload callback by selecting `No Wrap - in <body>` in the second dropdown in the left panel

```
function myFunction()
{
alert("Hello World!");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/E2gWP/)

Comment: closest to the perfect answer. part 3 wasn't answered tho. tks

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is library of javascript function and you need to add jquery file in html file that y jquery function was not working and for javacript function you need to change the setting in jfiddele left to no-wrap in head

http://jsfiddle.net/aLhb8/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/hushme/QaHda/10/

here is code

```
$("button").on("click", function () {

    $("p").text("this text will now appear!!")

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have internet connection, This should work

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').click(function() {
            alert("This is a simple alert message");   
        });        
    });
```

But if don't then just download the jquery framework and include into your page

Hope it helps and anyway jquery is a framework of javascript, so they are both or they are the same. Don't confuse yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JavaScript version - http://jsfiddle.net/aLhb8/4/

JavaScript

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
   alert(myButton.textContent);
});
```

Check this link out if you want to start learning more about JavaScript - http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/

Answer (score 0):

For the pure JS code, on the top left panel, select 'No wrap - in body'. This will make your code run without a problem.

In the jQuery code, make sure you've selected the jQuery library, as opposed to pure JS. You hadn't selected this before, so your code was invalid.